# Why are my Volley GET requests so slow?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm making a JSON request using volley. In a browser, this request takes ~200 ms. In my app, the same request is taking an average of 5.5 seconds (sometimes as high as 7-8 seconds). Here is my code:

```
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //done, parse result
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //error
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
```

I went ahead and did the same request using OkHttp and the result is around 1.5-2 seconds. Why is this taking so long using Volley? (Obvious answer would be to use OkHttp, but it would be a significant amount of work to replace all requests in my app with OkHttp syntax). Am I doing something wrong in my code or maybe not utilizing something in Volley?

Comment: Try StringRequest instead of JsonArrayRequest and check the time again. maybe the time consuming proccess is in processing the string into Json array by volley